# rpm-maven-plugin postinstallScriptlet example

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, rpm

I want to build a rpm and run 2 script after installation.
How can I achieve that by rpm-maven-plugin.
For example, my script is:

```
/opt/sss/${component.name}/bin/mkdir.sh
/opt/sss/${component.name}/bin/starter.sh
```

Below is my current pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>2.0-beta-3</version> -->
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>rpm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <group>Applications</group>
                    <release>1</release>
                    <name>${component.name}</name>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <mappings>
                       <mapping>
                        <directory>/opt/sss/${component.name}/bin</directory>
                            <filemode>775</filemode>
                            <username>root</username>
                            <groupname>super</groupname>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    <location>bin</location>
                                </source>
                            </sources>
                        </mapping>
                    </mappings>
                    <postinstallScriptlet>bin/mkdir.sh</postinstallScriptlet>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I got this error when run it:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:rpm (default-rpm) on project installation: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:rpm for parameter postinstallScriptlet: Cannot configure instance of org.codehaus.mojo.rpm.Scriptlet from
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for 1 script. I will update this answer when I tried how to set 2 script files.

```
            <postinstallScriptlet>
                <scriptFile>bin/mkdir.sh</scriptFile>
                <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
            </postinstallScriptlet>
```

Comment: postinstallScriptlet is a single script where you can do everything, for example execute other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to encapsulate both the script invocations in single script. Like :

Say you have two scripts :

> **script1.sh** and 
>   **script2.sh**

Write a wrapper script (wrapper.sh):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> script1.sh --some-args
> script2.sh --some-args
> ```

Now Invoke the postInstallScriptlet via maven :

> ```
> <postinstallScriptlet>
>    <scriptFile>......./wrapper.sh</scriptFile>
>    <fileEncoding>utf-8</fileEncoding>
> </postinstallScriptlet>
> ```

This is nothing to do with PostInstallScriptlet, But just a work around. If someone finds a better way to do this, Happy to accept theirs !!

If you are looking to learn more about advanced parameters, here it is : http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/adv-params.html